# Parsing a CSV file and Hashing

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, hash

I am trying to parse a CSV file to read in all the other zip codes. I am trying to create a hash where each key is a zip code and the value is the number it appears in the file. Then I want to print out the contents as Zip Code - Number. Here is the Perl script I have so far.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = qw (
     zipcode count
);

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need CSV file on command line \n";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file $!\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
   chomp $line;
   my @fields = split "," , $line;
   if (exists($hash{$fields[2]})) {
        $hash{$fields[1]}++;
   }else {
        $hash{$fields[1]} = 1;
   }
}

my $key;
my $value;
while (($key, $value) = each(%hash)) {
  print "$key - $value\n";
}

exit;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: there seems to be some bugs with the fields[1] variable. When I run it, it says it's uninitialized.

Comment: What does your sample input data look like; what is the matching desired output?  Is there any danger that the data contains quoted fields?  If so, what about commas inside quoted fields?  You probably need to use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) if there are any quirks in the input data at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  (I missed that the first time.)  You test `exists($hash{$fields[2]})` but then process `$hash{$fields[1]}++`...is this all the trouble?

Comment: One line looks like :
511 Marshall Square                 44965  Rosemount            Connecticut     689-068-3997

Comment: Please edit the question to include the data.  There's no comma in what you show, which is confusing.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for noticing that. But I'm still getting some error "Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in hash element at C:\...\example.pl line 18, <$data> line 33" for each line essentially

Comment: If there are no commas in your 'CSV file', then the `split` only creates a single entry, `$fields[0]`, so `$fields[1]` is indeed `undef`, just as the warning says.

Comment: You're right, I was told it was a .csv file but there don't seem to be any commas in text file at all. I think they are separated by tabs. Do I then just change the , to \t?

Comment: @user1091783: Yes, it sounds like it's a tab-separated file. Use `split /\t/, $line` instead.

Comment: I assume you meant `my %hash = ('zipcode', undef, 'count, undef);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say which column your zip code is in, but you are using the third field to check for an existing hash element, and then the second field to increment it.

There is no need to check whether a hash element already exists: Perl will happily create a non-existent hash element and increment it to 1 the first time you access it.

There is also no need to explicitly open any files passed as command line parameters: Perl will open them and read them if you use the `<>` operator without a file handle.

This reworking of your own program may work. It assumes the zip code is in the second column of the CSV. If it is anywhere else just change `++$hash{$fields[1]}` appropriately.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "Need CSV file on command line \n";

my %counts;

while (my $line = <>) {
   chomp $line;
   my @fields = split /,/, $line;
   ++$counts{$fields[1]};
}

while (my ($key, $value) = each %counts) {
  print "$key - $value\n";
}
```

Comment: oh, Perl so sweet :) and if you forget coffee, Perl will bring it to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is off-topic, but if you're on a system with the standard Unix text processing tools, you could use this command to count the number of occurrences of each value in field #2, and not need to write any code.

```
cut -d, -f2 filename.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

which will generate something like this output, where the count is listed first, and the zipcode second:

```
12 12345
2 56789
34 78912
1 90210
```